# Escaping the output of date in a BASH script

Tags: bash, date, curl, escaping

I'm working on what should be a very simple BASH script. What I want to do is a pull an image from a webcamera using curl and write it to a file whose name is datestamped.

```
#! /bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M)
DIRECTORY1=home/manager/security_images/Studio_1/
TARGET1=${DIRECTORY1}${DATE}.jpg

curl http://web@192.168.180.211/snapshot.cgi > $TARGET1
```

When I try to run this I am told that there is no such file or directory. I believe this is due to an error in my escaping but I have tried seemingly every combination of quotation marks around the variables at each stage and still can't get it to work. I just don't understand what is going wrong and could really use some pointers towards what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s just a typo.

```
DIRECTORY1=home/manager/security_images/Studio_1/
          ^^
```

Should be

```
DIRECTORY1=/home/manager/security_images/Studio_1/
```

of course.

As for escaping, even though only safe characters are used now, so quotes are technically superfluous, quoting out *all* `$variables` in *every* line by default is a good habit in shell scripting, there are very few cases when you do not want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Double quoting the redirection target should be enough:

```
curl http://web@192.168.180.211/snapshot.cgi > "$TARGET1"
```

Just make sure the path to it exists. You can run your script with

```
set -xv
```

to see how variables are interpolated.